# add more add less using jquery clone with incrementing id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Curerntly working on jquery clone where I need to addrow and delete rows I have searched lot in stackoverflow and in google based on that i understand a bit on how jquery clone will work.

Any suggestion please

Here is the jquery code.

```
        var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".phn_btn_more", function () { 
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row:eq(0)').clone();
        //alert("Clone number" + clone);
         $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        $('.cloned-row:eq(0)').after($clone);
    });

$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
    var len = $('.cloned-row').length;
    if(len>1){
        $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

With the current code updated code I can able to increment id dynamically but it cloning two times.

with this code when i try to click add more button it was cloning the div but i am getting two div instead of one and Iam trying to add id and name incrementing dynamically

I know it may be a possible duplicate but still I am not getting why I am not able to incrementing id and name. For btn less for the first div btn_less class won't be available once user click add more from second add less button should appear

Here is the html code

```
 <div class="em_pho cloned-row" id="phone_content">
                         <select id="sel_phntype" name="sel_phntype" class="sslt_Field">
                            <option selected='selected' value="">Phone Type</option>
                            <option value="BUSN">Business</option>
                            <option value="CAMP">Campus</option>
                            <option value="CELL" >Cellphone</option>
                            <option value="CEL2">Cellphone2</option>
                            <option value="FAX">FAX</option>
                            <option value="HOME">Home</option>
                            <option value="OTR">Other</option>
                         </select>
                         <span class = "ph-inline">
                            <input type="text" class="cc_field" placeholder="Country Code" id="txt_CC" maxlength="3" name="txt_CC" /> 
                            <input type="text" class="pn_field" placeholder="Phone Number" id="txt_Pno" name="txt_Pno" />
                            <input type="radio" name="preferred" id="rad_Prf" value="preferred">
                            <label class="radio-label">Preferred</label>
                            <!--<button class="btn_more" id="buttonvalue"></button>-->
                            <input type="button" class="phn_btn_more" id="buttonvalue"/>
                         </span>
                      </div>
```

Kindly help me

Thanks & regards
mahadevan

Comment: maybe not going to solve this specific problem, but if you located things based on class or ID attributes specifically set in HTML for your JS to hook into, you'd have a lot fewer problems than if you use lines like `parent().parent().parent().` which tightly tie your JS to your HTML

Comment: Hi @ToniLeigh first of all my clone is not working in properly :( i am not able to clone single by single with id it was generating three at time kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwd0L0ur/1/)

Let me know if I missed out anything or if anything is wrong.

JQuery

```
var count=0;

    $(document).on("click", ".phn_btn_more", function () { 
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row:eq(0)').clone();
        //alert("Clone number" + clone);
         $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
         $clone.find('.phn_btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1' id='buttonless' value = 'remove'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        $(this).parents('.em_pho').after($clone);
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
        var len = $('.cloned-row').length;
        if(len>1){
            $(this).parents('.em_pho').remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you guide me how to validate the field when the fields cloned

Comment: What do you mean by validate the field?

Comment: jquery field validation where if any field is null or we will throw an error class to say please enter the text field

Comment: So I suppose you want to check if Country Code and Phone Number are not empty when cloning. See if this is what you wanted [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwd0L0ur/2/)

Comment: Sorry @TheOneAndOnly I am disturbing you a lot. not like this Two scnearios when the user type the value in parent div if they click add more button in the clone the text field should be clear. second If the user not entering any values if the user click the submit button it should say please enter the value

Comment: For clearing the text field after clicking "Add More" button [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwd0L0ur/3/). As for validation after pressing submit button, you might want to try out [Basic JQuery Form Validation](http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89246/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-theoneandonly).